# how to iterate over json data recursively

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How to search over json data by given Jtoken key, this Jtoken can be everywhere in json data. I found below code and it works, but since json is new for me, just want to know if any better solution

```
       //resources is some json data
       JToken node = JToken.Parse(resources);

        var ids = new List<string>();

        WalkNode(node, n =>
        {
            JToken token = n["OrderId"];
            if (token != null && token.Type == JTokenType.String)
                mediaLinkHrefs.Add(token.Value<string>());
        });



    private static void WalkNode(JToken node, Action<JObject> action)
    {
        if (node.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            action((JObject)node);

            foreach (JProperty child in node.Children<JProperty>())
            {
                WalkNode(child.Value, action);
            }
        }
        else if (node.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            foreach (JToken child in node.Children())
            {
                WalkNode(child, action);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your json, what do you want to achive? Most probably you don't need a recursive method....

Comment: Better solution in regards to what? Speed, memory consumption, something else?

Comment: above code will work for any json data, just want to see if anyone here have better code but implement same arithmetic.

Comment: Good example to an [XY-Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=xy+problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the faster way like :

Go to http://json2csharp.com/ paste your json it will create a custom class/es derived from your json.

Make your call using javascriptserializer in syster.web.script.serialization

Assume that you have your json response put into S string ad your class is named RootObject

```
string S = JSON;
javascriptserializer js = new javascriptserializer();
RootObject o = js.deserialize<RootObject>(S);

dim S a string=JSON 'your json string
dim jsas new javascriptserializer
dim o as RootObject=js.deserialize(of RootObject)(s)
```

Then you may simply use linq and that's all.

3 lines of code :D

Hope that could help you.